# Jhipster default generated app deployed to Pivotal CF will not authenticate

Tags: jhipster, cloud-foundry

created a default `Jhipster app`, followed the `Jhipster` Deploying to Cloud Foundry instructions, `PCF` created the service just fine, the application Started fine, but will not accept the admin/admin login, I queried the service database using , I see the admin entry `(admin $2a$10$gSAhZrxMllrbgj/kkK9Uce...)` I even tried using the password for `giggles`. But the app will not authenticate the admin, or user Account, what am I missing ?

**I checked PCF / Web Service App Logs and found:**

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
>   2019-03-04T16:01:34.944-07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-03-04 23:01:34.937 ERROR 14 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter : Forwarding to error page from request [/api/account] due to exception [Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection]

Not sure where this will take me, so what am I missing ?

Comment: It sounds like there's some sort of database error. Do you see anything else in the logs? Did you remember to bind the service instance to your app?

Comment: Yes sir, I used ElephantSQL, That show I was able to see the admin row in the db, using the manager in the Pivotal Web Service management console, I deployed the application using the "prod" profile, per the JHipster instructions - gradlew -Pprod bootWar

cf push -f ./deploy/cloudfoundry/manifest.yml -p build/libs/*.war

Comment: Yes sir, I used ElephantSQL, That howI was able to see the admin row in the db, using the manager in the Pivotal Web Service management console, I deployed the application using the "prod" profile, per the JHipster instructions -   
1. gradlew -Pprod bootWar

2. cf push -f ./deploy/cloudfoundry/manifest.yml -p build/libs/*.war - It feels like something is missing in the instructions ?

Comment: OK, do you see any more output from the app when it fails? Try running `cf logs` in one terminal then `cf push` in another, or click the Metrics link in the PWS Management Console under your app (you can see up to two weeks of logs there). If there's a full stack trace it could give more clues as to why it's failing, often there will be a "Cause" section. Sorry, I'm not familiar with JHipster so I don't know what the demo is doing/supposed to do.